# Swift 5: I have a problem when I try to instantiate a viewmodel for testing

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swift5

I'm trying to instantiate my viewmodel for testing, in this case I don't need its parameters, but as it asks me to add them, when I try I get an error "Constant 'data' used before being initialized"

This is my code:

```
struct Account: Codable {
    let details: [Details]?

}

struct Details: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let currency: String?
    let interest: Float64?
    let date: String?
}
class DetailViewModel {

    private let data: Details?
    
    init(data: Details) {
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
class DetailViewModelTest: QuickSpec {
    override func spec() {
                
        var viewModel : DetailViewModel!
        let data: Details!
        viewModel = DetailViewModel(data: data) // I have error in this line
  }
}
```

Is there a way to instantiate my viewmodel without parameters? Or a better way to handle this?

Comment: can you add your Details code here.

Comment: `let data: Details!`: You just defined `data`, you never created it (ie, `data = ...)`. That's what is saying the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Details in a test with hardcoded values you either need to create it from some json or add another `init` to initialise all values, here I am using the latter. I am adding it in an extension and created a static method that uses the init to create an object with hard coded values.

```
extension Details {
    private init(id: String, currency: String, interest: Float64, date: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.currency = currency
        self.interest = interest
        self.date = date
    }

    static func createStub() -> Details {
        Details(id: "1", currency: "EUR", interest: 1.23, date: "2022-02-12")
    }
}
```

This is one way of doing it, the `init` could be designed in many ways but this is to show you how to move forward.

This can then be used in the test class

```
class DetailViewModelTest: QuickSpec {
    override func spec() {
        let viewModel = DetailViewModel(data: Details.createStub())
    //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should:

```
let data: Details = Details() // create your data
```

Comment: Thanks but when i try it, i have this error in let data... Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call. Insert 'from: <#Decoder#>'. 
Do you know how I can solve it?